# I "need" a cool way to write (x == 0 ? 1 : 0)

Tags: c#, bit-shift

So I have a piece of my code where I have a variable that is either `0` or `1` and I want to get the opposite. In actuality it is an `enum` and my exact code is

```
_Player other = player == _Player.FIRST ? _Player.SECOND : _Player.FIRST;
```

but I'm wondering whether there's a fancy bitshift way of doing this.

Comment: use boolean instead, and negate the property `_Player other = !player`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [extension method for enum type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383974.aspx) : a cool **and readable** way !

```
enum Player
{
    FIRST,
    SECOND
}

static class PlayerMethods
{

    public static String swap(this Player s)
    {
        switch (s1)
        {
            case Player.FIRST:
                return Player.SECOND;
            case Player.SECOND:
                return Player.FIRST;            
        }
    }
}
```

and use it :

```
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player one = Player.FIRST;
        Player other = one.Swap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One cool way, is using,

```
x = !x
```

when x is a boolean